# Testing if a method returns a `non-null` value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im testing if my method `populate()` returns a non-null value (which it does, it returns an integer > 0) but having troubles to correctly write it. I have:

```
describe House::Room do
  describe '.populate' do
    let(:info) {
      $info = {"people"=>
                        {"name"=>"Jordan",
                         "last_name"=>"McClalister"}}
              }
    it 'should return an integer > 0' do
      expect(House::Room.populate(info)).not_to eq(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: First thing to remove here is `$info =`. Not needed. Your expectation is not matching with the subject. So write what you are testing. That helps readability.

Comment: In Ruby `$` means *global variable* and that usually means you're doing something wrong. These are almost always a bad plan and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, should be just `info` ?

Comment: The block returns value will be assigned to the `let(:info)` by default. So you don't need anything except the `Hash` there.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, i don't really get what you're saying

Comment: mike `let(:info) {
      {"people"=>
                        {"name"=>"Jordan",
                         "last_name"=>"McClalister"}}
              }` is enough. clear now?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to change the let assignment to:

```
describe House::Room do
  describe '.populate' do
    let(:info) {"people"=>
                        {"name"=>"Jordan",
                         "last_name"=>"McClalister"}
               }
    it 'should return an integer > 0' do
      expect(House::Room.populate(info)).not_to be(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

That should make your code work as you expect.

However, you could also use another matcher, like 'be_within' if you wanted to be more specific, or write several expect statements in the same test, like 'expect to be an integer', 'expect to be greater than 0', etc...  There is no limit to the number of expect statements you can have in an 'it' block, the test will only pass if all of the expectations are fulfilled.  (That said, I believe best practice would be to split it up into individual tests.)

Answer (score 0):

[rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rspec) favors `be_nil` over `be(nil)`, according to [RSpec/BeNil](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/BeNil).

Thus, the answer provided by @GabrielBonner is better expressed as:

```rb
describe House::Room do
  describe '.populate' do
    let(:info) {"people"=>
                        {"name"=>"Jordan",
                         "last_name"=>"McClalister"}
               }
    it 'should return an integer > 0' do
      expect(House::Room.populate(info)).not_to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```